# Create reusable Excel Styles for C# interop objects

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm generating a couple of spreadsheets using C#, and I'm trying to create a reusable [Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.style.aspx) that can be applied to specific ranges in each spreadsheet. The issue I'm having is that the Excel process is not exiting correctly when my method finishes executing. In fact, I've been able to narrow the problem area down to the point in the code where I'm creating the Excel `Style`.

```
Workbooks books = excelApplication.Workbooks;
_Workbook wBook = books.Add("");
_Worksheet wSheet = (_Worksheet)wBook.ActiveSheet;

Styles styles = wBook.Styles;
Style columnHeader = styles.Add("ColumnHeader");
columnHeader.Font.Size = 12; // if I comment this out, excel quits correctly

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wSheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(books);
```

The style works as expected when I apply it, but the Excel process doesn't quit when I quit my excelApplication. If I comment out the line `columnHeader.Font.Size = 12;`, the Excel process correctly exits. Am I missing something?

**Update**
I modified Govert's sample WinForms application to reflect the structure of my class, which is creating multiple spreadsheets. His application properly exited the Excel process, but my modified version does not:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExcelCOMReferenceTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Excel.Application excelApplication;
        private Excel.Style columnHeader;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DoMyExcelStuff();
            GarbageCleanup();
        }

        private void DoMyExcelStuff()
        {
            StartExcel();
            var wBook = GenerateWorksheet();

            excelApplication.Range["A1"].Value = "Name";
            excelApplication.Range["A1"].Style = columnHeader;
            wBook.SaveAs(@"c:\Test\tst" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mmss") + ".xlsx");

            // No need for Marshal.ReleaseComObject(...)
            // No need for ... = null
            StopExcel();
        }

        private void StartExcel()
        {
            excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
            excelApplication.Visible = false;
        }

        private void StopExcel()
        {
            excelApplication.UserControl = false;
            excelApplication.Quit();
        }

        private Excel._Workbook GenerateWorksheet()
        {
            Excel.Workbooks books = excelApplication.Workbooks;
            Excel.Workbook wBook = books.Add("");

            Excel.Styles styles = wBook.Styles;
            columnHeader = styles.Add("ColumnHeader");
            columnHeader.Font.Size = 12;
            columnHeader.Font.Bold = true;

            return wBook;
        }

        private void GarbageCleanup()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never need to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` in this context. The runtime is perfectly able to keep track of COM objects and release them when they are no longer referenced. Calling `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is a confusing anti-pattern that sadly even some Microsoft documentation mistakenly suggests. You also don't have to set *local* variables to `null` - the references will be out of scope when the method completes.

To get Excel to close, you need to call `excelApplication.Quit()`, then make sure you have no live references to Excel COM objects, then call the garbage collector to clean up. You should call the garbage collector twice - you might have cases where the references form a cycle, and the first GC call will break the cycle, but the COM objects might only get properly released on the second call.

You also have to be careful with this kind of code in debug builds. References in a method are artificially kept alive until the end of the method so that they will still be accessible in the debugger. This means your local Excel COM objects might not be cleaned up by calling the GC inside that method. To avoid this issue, you might follow a pattern like this:

```
public void DoMyExcelStuffAndCleanup()
{
    DoMyExcelStuff();
    // Call GC twice to ensure that cleanup after cycles happens immediately
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}

public void DoMyExcelStuff()
{
    Application excelApplication = ...
    // Here you access all those Excel objects ...
    // No need for Marshal.ReleaseComObject(...)
    // No need for ... = null
    excelApplication.Quit();
}
```

---

I've now tested with a new WinForms application, to which I add a single button and this code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WinFormsComCleanup
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DoMyExcelStuff();
            GarbageCleanup();
        }

        private void DoMyExcelStuff()
        {
            Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbooks books = excelApplication.Workbooks;
            Excel.Workbook wBook = books.Add("");
            Excel.Worksheet wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wBook.ActiveSheet;

            Excel.Styles styles = wBook.Styles;
            Excel.Style columnHeader = styles.Add("ColumnHeader");
            columnHeader.Font.Size = 12;
            columnHeader.Font.Bold = true;
            excelApplication.Range["A1"].Value = "Name";
            excelApplication.Range["A1"].Style = columnHeader;
            wBook.SaveAs(@"c:\Temp\tst" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mmss") +".xlsx");

            // No need for Marshal.ReleaseComObject(...)
            // No need for ... = null
            excelApplication.Quit();
        }

        private void GarbageCleanup()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected, with the Excel process stopping during the `GarbageCleanup()` call.

---

**Update**

After the update to the question, I suggest the following modification:

```
    private void StopExcel()
    {

        excelApplication.UserControl = false;
        excelApplication.Quit();

        // Set the form-level variables to null, so that no live references to Excel remain
        columnHeader = null;
        excelApplication = null;
    }
```

This will ensure that the object-level fields that are introduced in the updated question have Excel their references removed before the GC runs.

In my testing, with this modification Excel quits again. This is consistent with my understanding that the .NET runtime properly keeps track of COM references, and that `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is never required for Excel interop.

Comment: I wasn't setting any local variables to null, but if I don't call `Marhsal.ReleaseComObject`, the garbage collector is not properly taking care of the COM objects.

Comment: Were you checking a Debug build? Was the GC.Collect() code in the same method as in your question? If so, you might need to check again.

Comment: Your application did indeed stop the Excel process correctly. I went a step further to modify the structure of your Form class to resemble mine, and was able to get the Excel process to hang around again. I've updated my question above.

Comment: OK - with your changes you set two object-level fields that hold references to COM objects. These references need to be cleared (by setting those fields to null) before calling the garbage collector. This is different to the local variables I mention, which do not require setting to null because they go out of scope at the end of the method.

Comment: See my updated answer for the extra cleanup you need if you introduce form-level references to the Excel COM objects.

Comment: @Govert This hasn't been good advice even for .NET Framework times, though it might have been possible to get away with it under certain circumstances (depending what your app does, how it is structured, what kind of COM objects you are using and if you can live with bad performance while the GC runs). However, for .NET (Core), this will not work when consuming local server COM objects (like Excel), because .NET (Core) does not run finalizers anymore, when your app exits. Therefore, the consumed objects will never get released on the local server side. If you consume something, release it!

Comment: @lauxjpn I would be very interested in learning more about possible COM problems under .NET 5+. I have done these same tests on .NET 5 and everything works the same and correctly in .NET 5 as under .NET Framework my tests so far. The COM references are released when the GC is run, the Excel process ends as expected and I see no problems. I've set up a test repo and good place for discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/govert/TestNet5Com Any input would be very welcome!

Comment: @Govert That is correct. As long as you force GC to run and you are not holding any active references to the objects of the COM server, GC will take care of releasing them. However, if you don't manually call GC multiple times, the client app exit in .NET (Core) will not release your RCWs anymore. Doing it in the proposed way might lead to unintended leaks or consequences for other COM servers than Excel, but for Excel, its probably fine due to the way it has been implemented. So let me retract my previous comment here in part, as it is not entirely targeted at the right post (about Excel).

Answer (score 1):

Probably a hanging reference to the Font / columnHeader or styles, accessing properties of properties in Excel interop can cause the Excel process to hang; try this

```
Workbooks books = excelApplication.Workbooks;
_Workbook wBook = books.Add("");
_Worksheet wSheet = (_Worksheet)wBook.ActiveSheet;

Styles styles = wBook.Styles;
Style columnHeader = styles.Add("ColumnHeader");
Font font = columnHeader.Font;
font.Size = 12;

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(font);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(columnHeader);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(styles);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wSheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(books);

font = null;
columnHeader = null;
styles = null;
wSheet = null;
wBook = null;
books = null;

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: No luck with this, the process is still hanging.

Comment: @GunnerBarnes Just noticed; are you doing a ReleaseComObject on your instance of excelApplication anywhere? (edited my code to add it)

Comment: Yes, I should have noted that in my code, but I am in fact already doing that at a later point. The Excel process quits as expected unless I set any properties on the Style.

Comment: ok .. give the updated version a try. It can be difficult to track this down, I feel your pain!

Comment: No difference with that either.